# Rollbar causing Heroku Node app to crash with throw new TypeError(`Expected a string, got "${typeof value}"`);

Tags: node.js, heroku, rollbar

I'm trying to deploy a node app to Heroku, but something related to the `request-ip` dependency of `Rollbar` is causing the app to crash.

The error message is:

```
throw new TypeError(`Expected a string, got "${typeof value}"`);
```

My `web.js` file looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config({silent: true});

var express = require('express');

var Rollbar = require('rollbar');
var rollbar = new Rollbar({
  accessToken: process.env.ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  captureUncaught: true,
  captureUnhandledRejections: true
});

var app = express();

app.use(rollbar.errorHandler());
```

The error is happening here:

```
/app/node_modules/rollbar/node_modules/request-ip/index.js:15
```

It appears the function `getClientIpFromXForwardedFor` in this module is not getting a `String` when it should be.

Anyone got any idea why this might be happening specifically on Heroku? I'm not having this problem locally.

Comment: Hi Peter - You can get help from the Rollbar team with this issue by contacting us via support@rollbar.com.  We provide full support to all customers, even if you're on a free plan.

Comment: Thanks @JesseGibbs. I worked out that the problem was just a strange combination of Node and other module versions I was running. Came back to mark this as answered. Made sure I was up to date on everything I was running and this problem went away. Thanks for following up though.